# Unexpected time axis min/max openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, date, charts, openpyxl

I am trying to plot a few charts with the openpyxl library, here is my code so far:

```
# openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl.chart import *
from openpyxl.chart.text import RichText
from openpyxl.drawing import *
from openpyxl.drawing.text import  RichTextProperties,Paragraph,ParagraphProperties, CharacterProperties
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle
from copy import deepcopy

# other
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
# define input and output files
file_input = r"C:\LocalData\VirtualEnvironment_terraphase\Project_PointMolate\Test_Data1.xlsx"
file_output = r"C:\LocalData\VirtualEnvironment_terraphase\Project_PointMolate\Test_Result1.xlsx"

# create workbook
wb = Workbook()
# create main data frame
df_main = pd.read_excel(file_input)
# determine number of columns in dataframe, this will be used later
df_main_range_columns = len(df_main.columns) + 1
# sort data frame
df_main = df_main.sort_values(by=['LocCode','ChemName','SampleDate'])
d={}

for index, LocCode in enumerate(df_main['LocCode'].unique()):
    d[LocCode] = df_main[df_main['LocCode'] == LocCode]
    
    df_local_range_rows = len(d[LocCode]) + 2
    
    # create charts
    chart_scatter_analytical = ScatterChart(auto_axis=False)
    chart_scatter_gwe = ScatterChart(auto_axis=False)
    
    # create sheets, one sheet per LocCode
    #    create data sheet
    dataSheetName = LocCode + '_data'
    wb.create_sheet(dataSheetName)
    ws = wb[dataSheetName]
    #    create chart sheet
    chartSheetName = LocCode + '_chart'
    wb.create_chartsheet(chartSheetName)
    cs = wb[chartSheetName]
    
    # add each dataframe to sheet
    for dataframes in dataframe_to_rows(d[LocCode], index=True, header=True):
        ws.append(dataframes)
        
#     # format dates
#     date_style_customX = NamedStyle(name='date_style_customX', number_format='m/d/yyyy h:mm')
    
#     for row in ws[2:ws.max_row]:
#         cell = row[2]
#         cell.style = date_style_customX
    
    # main loop, start by looping through analytes
    for index, Analyte in enumerate(d[LocCode]['ChemName'].unique()):
        # get column indices
        #    loop through each column headers, see if column header matches columns of interest (e.g. date, concentration, analyte, etc.) 
        for column in ws.iter_cols(min_row=1, max_row=1, min_col=1, max_col=df_main_range_columns):
            for cell in column:
                if cell.value == 'SampleDate':
                    col_date = cell.column
                elif cell.value == 'Concentration':
                    col_conc = cell.column
                elif cell.value == 'ChemName':
                    col_analyte = cell.column
                    
        # get row indices for analyte
        #    create empty list to add row indices to
        row_analyte_list = []
        #    loop through each row (for each analyte) and add row indices to row list
        for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, max_row=df_local_range_rows, min_col=col_analyte, max_col=col_analyte):            
            for cell in row:
                if cell.value == Analyte:
                    row_analyte_list.append(cell.row)
        
        row_min = min(row_analyte_list)
        row_max = max(row_analyte_list)      
        
        data_x = Reference(ws, 
                           min_col=col_date, 
                           max_col=col_date, 
                           min_row=row_min, 
                           max_row=row_max)
        
        data_y = Reference(ws, 
                           min_col=col_conc, 
                           max_col=col_conc,
                           min_row=row_min, 
                           max_row=row_max)

        # create series
        series_analyte = Series(values = data_y, xvalues=data_x, title=Analyte)
        
        # style series
        series_analyte.marker.symbol = 'auto'
        # series_analyte.marker.graphicalProperties.solidFill = 'ffffff'
        
        # add series to charts
        # add analytical results to one chart, GWE to another
        if Analyte == 'GWE':
            chart_scatter_gwe.series.append(series_analyte)
        else:
            chart_scatter_analytical.series.append(series_analyte)
    
    # define no line style for gridlines
    sgp = shapes.GraphicalProperties(ln=line.LineProperties(noFill=True))
    
    # style charts
    # style gwe chart, this serves as the 'main' chart, since the analytical will be added to it
    chart_scatter_gwe.title = LocCode
    #    configure y-axis
    chart_scatter_gwe.y_axis.title = 'Elevation (ft)'
    chart_scatter_gwe.y_axis.majorGridlines.spPr = sgp
    chart_scatter_gwe.y_axis.majorTickMark = 'out'
    #    configure x-axis
    chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.title = 'Date'
    chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.number_format = 'd-mmm-yyyy'
    chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.txPr = deepcopy(chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.title.text.rich)
    chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.txPr.properties.rot = "-2700000" # this value is in 60,000ths of a degree, so 45 degrees = 2,700,000, 60,000th degrees (see the comments in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146418/rotate-the-axis-of-an-excel-chart-using-openpyxl)
    chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.majorTickMark = 'out'
    # chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.majorUnit = 31
    #     these two lines set the min/max of the x-axis, these are included here for testing purposes but will need to be changed in any actual project work
    # chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.scaling.min = 44562.0
    # chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.scaling.max = 44655.0
    
    # style analytical chart
    chart_scatter_analytical.y_axis.title = 'Concentration'
    chart_scatter_analytical.y_axis.majorTickMark = 'out'
    
    # configure axes
    chart_scatter_analytical.y_axis.axId = 200
    chart_scatter_gwe.y_axis.crosses = "max"
    
    # combine charts
    chart_scatter_gwe += chart_scatter_analytical
        
    # add chart to sheet
    cs.add_chart(chart_scatter_gwe)
   
    
wb.save(file_output)
```

Here is my test input data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qYtdmipPPwvlqupUY8Hgvz6saVXUM7WL/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104041081140482661384&rtpof=true&sd=true

I'm expecting the code to produce 3 charts, one for each monitoring well (mw) in the LocCode column, that should look like this:

[image]

Well, I get the above chart for MW04, but the charts for the other two monitoring wells look like this:

[image]

It appears the date axis min/max are being automatically calculated, but are calculated wrong for MW02 and MW03, but correctly for MW04.

Any ideas on why this might be? Or any other tips for working with date axis for charts with openpyxl?

Thanks,

Comment: This is likely to be due to issue with Dateformat. Do ````df_main.info()```` and correct data errors. I tried running the code, but cannot as required libraries are missing. Line 89 ````Series```` not defined

Comment: For "some reason" it is connected to the years 2000-2001. If these years get removed from a dataset, the excel auto scaling works fine.

Comment: Scatterchart has a default NumericAxis. Maybe that's the culprit here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859646/how-to-display-date-format-in-openpyxl-chart where switching from Scatterchart to Linechart resolved the issus.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you for looking into this, I'll look more into the dates, especially the 2000-2001 range. I'll also try switching to Linechart and see what works best. Will report back later.

Comment: @Redox the dates were in fact not formatted as dates, df_main.info() helped me see that. Unfortunately changing this did not fix the error in the charts.

Comment: There's an awful lot of code in the loop which makes debugging a lot harder. Date axes are indeed not suitable for scatter charts. These are best used only where y = f(x).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Scatterchart is causing issues, when I switch to Linechart the issue is resolved. Thanks to @Christian for suggesting this.

Here is my code now, which is working as expected:

```
# openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl.chart import *
from openpyxl.chart.text import RichText
from openpyxl.chart.axis import DateAxis
from openpyxl.drawing import *
from openpyxl.drawing.text import  RichTextProperties,Paragraph,ParagraphProperties, CharacterProperties
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle
from copy import deepcopy

# other
import pandas as pd

# define input and output files
file_input = r"C:\LocalData\VirtualEnvironment_terraphase\Project_PointMolate\Test_Data1.xlsx"
file_output = r"C:\LocalData\VirtualEnvironment_terraphase\Project_PointMolate\Test_Result1b.xlsx"

# create workbook
wb = Workbook()

# create main data frame
df_main = pd.read_excel(file_input)

# determine number of columns in dataframe, this will be used later
df_main_range_columns = len(df_main.columns) + 1

# sort data frame
df_main = df_main.sort_values(by=['LocCode','ChemName','SampleDate'])
d={}

for index, LocCode in enumerate(df_main['LocCode'].unique()):
    d[LocCode] = df_main[df_main['LocCode'] == LocCode]
    
    df_local_range_rows = len(d[LocCode]) + 2
    
    # create charts
    chart_scatter_analytical = LineChart()
    chart_scatter_gwe = LineChart()
    
    # create sheets, one sheet per LocCode
    #    create data sheet
    dataSheetName = LocCode + '_data'
    wb.create_sheet(dataSheetName)
    ws = wb[dataSheetName]
    
    #    create chart sheet
    chartSheetName = LocCode + '_chart'
    wb.create_chartsheet(chartSheetName)
    cs = wb[chartSheetName]
    
    # add each dataframe to sheet
    for dataframes in dataframe_to_rows(d[LocCode], index=True, header=True):
        ws.append(dataframes)
    
    # main loop, start by looping through analytes
    for index, Analyte in enumerate(d[LocCode]['ChemName'].unique()):
        # get column indices
        #    loop through each column headers, see if column header matches columns of interest (e.g. date, concentration, analyte, etc.) 
        for column in ws.iter_cols(min_row=1, max_row=1, min_col=1, max_col=df_main_range_columns):
            for cell in column:
                if cell.value == 'SampleDate':
                    col_date = cell.column
                elif cell.value == 'Concentration':
                    col_conc = cell.column
                elif cell.value == 'ChemName':
                    col_analyte = cell.column
                    
        # get row indices for analyte
        #    create empty list to add row indices to
        row_analyte_list = []
        #    loop through each row (for each analyte) and add row indices to row list
        for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, max_row=df_local_range_rows, min_col=col_analyte, max_col=col_analyte):            
            for cell in row:
                if cell.value == Analyte:
                    row_analyte_list.append(cell.row)
        
        row_min = min(row_analyte_list)
        row_max = max(row_analyte_list)      
        
        data_x = Reference(ws, 
                           min_col=col_date, 
                           max_col=col_date, 
                           min_row=row_min, 
                           max_row=row_max)
        
        data_y = Reference(ws, 
                           min_col=col_conc, 
                           max_col=col_conc,
                           min_row=row_min, 
                           max_row=row_max)
        
        # add data to charts
        if Analyte == 'GWE':
            chart_scatter_gwe.add_data(data_y)
            chart_scatter_gwe.set_categories(data_x)
        else:
            chart_scatter_analytical.add_data(data_y)
            chart_scatter_analytical.set_categories(data_x)
    
    #######################################################################################################
    # style charts
    #  style gwe chart, this serves as the 'main' chart, since the analytical will be added to it
    chart_scatter_gwe.title = LocCode
    #    configure y-axis
    chart_scatter_gwe.y_axis.title = 'Elevation (ft)'
    chart_scatter_gwe.y_axis.majorTickMark = 'out'
    #    configure x-axis
    chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.title = 'Date'
    chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.number_format = 'd-mmm-yyyy'
    chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.txPr = deepcopy(chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.title.text.rich)
    chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.txPr.properties.rot = "-2700000" # this value is in 60,000ths of a degree, so 45 degrees = 2,700,000, 60,000th degrees (see the comments in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146418/rotate-the-axis-of-an-excel-chart-using-openpyxl)
    chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.majorTickMark = 'out'
    chart_scatter_gwe.x_axis.majorUnit = 31
    #    define no line style for gridlines
    sgp = shapes.GraphicalProperties(ln=line.LineProperties(noFill=True))
    chart_scatter_gwe.y_axis.majorGridlines.spPr = sgp
    
    #  style analytical chart
    chart_scatter_analytical.y_axis.title = 'Concentration'
    chart_scatter_analytical.y_axis.majorTickMark = 'out'
    #######################################################################################################
    
    # configure axes
    chart_scatter_analytical.y_axis.axId = 200
    chart_scatter_gwe.y_axis.crosses = "max"
    
    # combine charts
    chart_scatter_gwe += chart_scatter_analytical
        
    # add chart to sheet
    cs.add_chart(chart_scatter_gwe)

wb.save(file_output)
```

I'm not sure why the Scatterchart method is not working, if anyone has insight to this or how to make it work correctly I'd be glad to hear it.